# If statement for ppActionRunMacro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
If ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Rectangle 5").ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = ppActionRunMacro(CorrectAnswer) Then
MsgBox "YEET"
End If
```

How do I make a MsgBox pop-up if a certain shape has a certain macro to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rectangle's ActionSettings are set like this

```
Sub Setup()
    Dim ppt As Presentation
    Set ppt = ActivePresentation

    With ppt.Slides(1).Shapes("Rectangle 3").ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
        .Action = ppActionRunMacro
        .Run = "CorrectAnswer"
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub CorrectAnswer()
    Debug.Print "show the correct answer"
End Sub
```

Then you can detect which shape has the macro you're looking for with

```
Sub test()
    Dim ppt As Presentation
    Set ppt = ActivePresentation

    Dim sld As Slide
    For Each sld In ppt.Slides
        Dim shp As Shape
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Name Like "Rectangle*" Then
                If shp.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Run = "CorrectAnswer" Then
                    MsgBox "YaYaYeet"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is causing you the error.

Following is the correct syntax:

```
.ActionSettings.(ppMouseClick).Run = "CorrectAnswer"
```